# how do you check if a column is a integer ssis derived column transformation expression?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Hi I'm doing a small project very new to SQL server business intelligence development studio with a dtsx package any help would be great.

i have a excel file with a column name Number which holds int values

I'm using Derived column transformation

any way i can use the expression to check if the value is a int?

if not a integer send error of some kind

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In C# we don't have IsNumeric(VB.Net) but we can use TryParse to achieve the same functionality

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{

    int result;
    if (int.TryParse(Row.Column.ToString(), out result))
    {
        Row.IsNumeric = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        Row.IsNumeric = 0;
    }

}
```

Same code in vb.Net is

```
 If IsNumeric(Row.Column) Then 
 Row.IsNumeric=1          // Create a `IsNumeric`  output column in script   transformation of data type int
 Else
 Row.IsNumeric=0
 End If
```

the above functionality can even be achieved in `Derived Column Transformation` using the expression

```
ISNULL((DT_I4)(Column) == (DT_I4)(Column) ? 1 : 0) ? 0 : 1
```

Check my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14228277/how-do-i-check-if-a-value-is-numeric-in-script-component-in-ssis-in-c-sharp) in SO

Comment: ic thank you how do i display to the user that the value is not numeric and stop the package?

Comment: You can use `Conditional Split Transformation` after the above code and check whether `IsNumeric==1` .For more information on that check this article `http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andy_leonard/archive/2009/02/20/ssis-expression-language-and-the-conditional-split-transformation.aspx`

Comment: displaying it to user ?? SSIS is not a front end application . For displaying r u using .NET or SSRS . If you simply intend to display a message to the user when the ssis package executes then use a script transformation and use `isNumeric==1?MessageBox.Show(Row.Column):Null`.This will create a pop up for the user when there is a number

Answer (score 0):

The SSIS expression language does not have an IsNumeric() function so the Derived Column component cannot be used to do the same. You will have to use the Script Component instead. The following code inside a script component will achieve the same.

```
Imports System.Math
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper

Public Class ScriptMain
   Inherits UserComponent

   Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)
        Dim retNum As Double
        'use TryParse to test if the value is numeric or not

        If System.Double.TryParse(Row.Column, retNum) Then
            Row.DirectRowToNumeric()
        Else
            Row.DirectRowToNonNumeric()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Hope this helps

Raj

Comment: will try it at work however is their a way to do it in C#? and how do i call the script?

Comment: Use Script task. Sorry I have no idea about C#. Maybe someone who know C# will be able to comment